# Find a function by name in Chrome's Devtools Performance

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a React component that uses a hook inside. It's more or less just a function within a function.

```
export const Comp: FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useSomeCustomHook(function someCallback() {});
  
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
};
```

After measuring performance using Chrome's Devtools, I can find how much time the function `Comp` took. There's no trace of functions `useSomeCustomHook` or `someCallback`, however. **How do I find them?**

The application was bootstrapped with `create-react-app`.

Comment: Oops, I already had the callback named. Fixed the sample code. (Still doesn't show.)

Comment: Use performance timing API inside the callback, [more info](https://www.debugbear.com/blog/custom-front-end-performance-metrics)/